# assigning to submatrix values of another submatrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change submatrix values using values from the another matrix of the same shape, as submatrix. I am planning to use list of columns/rows indices to choose the desirable submatrix, but I am totally confused on the step of the new values assignment.

```
A = np.zeros((10, 10))
B = np.ones((4,4))
A[[9,3,4,5],:][:,[9,3,4,5]] = B
print(A)
```

but matrix A doesn't change at all..

Comment: Matrix A does not change because you're using two indexing steps. The first of these (`A[[9,3,4,5],:]`) creates a copy of rows `[9,3,4,5]`, but the second indexing step (`[:,[9,3,4,5]] = B`) then modifies this copy, not the original matrix `A`.

You should use a single indexing step instead. Make sure that the indices broadcast with each other; typically via `np.ix_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_):

```
A[np.ix_([9,3,4,5], [9,3,4,5])] = B

print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]]
```